# Regular Expression course grade

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression search in JavaScript that would accept on of the following grades: `A, B+, B, C+, C, D, F, AF, or WF`.

I have the following regular expression: `^A-?|[BCD][+-]?|[AW]?F|W$`

I would be happy if it can at least match the first letter and a second character, if any.

Comment: this doesn't seem like the job for a regex, since you already known in advance the only possible valid input values.

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: Does the one you gave not work?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: `^(?:AF?|[BC]\+?|[DF]|WF)$` will match all 9 examples and only all 9 examples, but I feel like there were some extra ones we were supposed to assume you wanted? `A-`, `D+`, etc. But the main point is make sure your alternation is nested in a group so that each option is anchored with `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in context matching either `A-` or `[AW]?F` this could get misinterpreted and match `A` and `F` as single characters instead of the actual complete subpattern you want to match.

```
var r = 'AF'.match(/^A-?|[BCD][+-]?|[AW]?F$/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]); //=> A
```

I would use a non-capturing group to group your expressions if you don't plan on listing them out.

```
var r = 'AF'.match(/^(?:A-?|[BCD][+-]?|[AW]?F)$/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]); //=> AF
```

Comment: THANKS!!! Made a small edit to suit my needs, but you pointed me in the right direction! This is what I used: `^(?:A|[BC][+]?|[AW]?F?|D?)$`

Comment: "following grades: A, B+, B, C+, C, D, F, AF, or WF" @hwnd Actually you could simplify to... `/^A|B\+|B|C\+|C|D|F|AF|WF$/` shortest doesn't mean maintainable... I dont even see the point of using a regex here.

Comment: @plalx I agree but `A` and `F` would still be separate in `AF` http://regex101.com/r/mE1aX8/1

Comment: @hwnd Yes, well you would have to put the longest matches at the beginning to fix this issue. `'AF'.match(/^AF|WF|A|B\+|B|C\+|C|D|F$/); //AF`

Comment: @hwnd How can keep validation for only A or B or C, single character?